# Problems specifying a single bucket in a simple AWS user policy

Tags: amazon-s3, policy, boto, bucket, amazon-iam

I'm using AWS IAM STS (via boto) to create credentials for my accessing an S3 bucket.  I'm at a loss as to what's wrong in the following policy.  I've simplified my policy down as much as possible and am still getting unexpected results.

When I get the token for the user I attach the following policy:

```
user_policy_string = r'{"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action": "s3:*","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"}]}'
```

This works, but is obviously a little too permissive.  In narrowing down the permissions associated with these credentials I attempt to use the same policy, but specify the bucket:

```
user_policy_string = r'{"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action": "s3:*","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::buck_binary_bucket_bay-earth-d5a/*"}]}'
```

Here I get 403 errors when I try to access S3.  Based on the AWS docs I'm sure this is the way to address a specific bucket in the policy, so I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this restriction.  Am I referring to the bucket incorrectly?

In the S3 console, the policy is empty (have tried adding a totally permissive policy as well).  For the AWS account used to generate the STS tokens, the policy is as follows:

```
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:GetFederationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:GetUser",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here I get 403 errors when I try to access S3.

How do you actually *try to access S3*, i.e. by means of which tool, service, API?

Quite often a use case involves S3 API calls addressing a different resource types as well besides the `Resource` targeted by the policy already. Specifically, you'll need to be aware of the difference between [Operations on the Service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPServiceOps.html) (e.g. [ListAllMyBuckets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/SOAPListAllMyBuckets.html)), [Operations on Buckets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPBucketsOps.html) (e.g. [ListBucket](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/SOAPListBucket.html)) and [Operations on Objects](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPObjectsOps.html) (e.g. [GetObject](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/SOAPGetObject.html)).

If your S3 access method implicitly uses any other resource types as well (i.e. besides the object resources you are already addressing via `buck_binary_bucket_bay-earth-d5a/*`), these require respective additional policies accordingly. For example, the common requirement of being able to list the objects in the bucket via *ListBucket* before accessing the objects themselves would require a respective policy fragment addressing the bucket like so:

```
   "Statement":[{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":"s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::buck_binary_bucket_bay-earth-d5a",
      }
   ]
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was *exactly* the problem.

Comment: AUGH.  AWS's policy mechanism is _aggravating_.  For reference, my specific issue (giving a user full access to a bucket) was solved by having the following line: "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"]

Comment: @Steffen : sir i have applied the policy to s3 to list a single bucket still when i log on to console i cant see any thing i get this error: `You dont have permission to access it`