# Why am I getting AccessDenied with videos?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Using AWS S3. I have a mixture of video and photo files. All of which are in their respective sub-directories. All files are set to private. I am getting `AccessDenied` when I try to access a video file. The other files are fine.

I tried this to no avail:

```
{
 "Id": "Policy1331547131417",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "Stmt1331546963174",
     "Action": [
       "*"
     ],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::actual_bucket_name_here/uploads/users/*/videos/*",
     "Principal": {
       "AWS": [
         "*"
       ]
     }
   },
   {
     "Sid": "Stmt1331547083926",
     "Action": [
       "*"
     ],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::actual_bucket_name_here/uploads/users/*/photos/*",
     "Principal": {
       "AWS": [
         "*"
       ]
     }
   },
   {
     "Sid": "Stmt1331547130024",
     "Action": [
       "*"
     ],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::actual_bucket_name_here/uploads/users/*/banners/*",
     "Principal": {
       "AWS": [
         "*"
       ]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

My bucket policy is the same for videos, photos, and banners. ACL permissions are also the same for all files. So why am I not able to access files from my videos directory?

Comment: By which means do you 'access' your video files, i.e. with which tool (JavaScript video player widget, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you actually try to access your video files, i.e. by means of which tool, service, API?

The access method in use might actually require permission for the `s3:ListBucket` action as well, e.g. a JavaScript video player widget might implicitly look for various file formats of the video in question to present a respective selection to your user - you'll need to be aware of the difference between [Operations on Buckets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPBucketsOps.html) (e.g. [ListBucket](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/SOAPListBucket.html)) and [Operations on Objects](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPObjectsOps.html) (e.g. [GetObject](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/SOAPGetObject.html)), see my answer to [Problems specifying a single bucket in a simple AWS user policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089457) for more details on this.

Extending your video bucket policy accordingly might remedy this issue, e.g. (policy fragment only):

```js
{
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": [
       "s3:ListBucket"
     ],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::actual_bucket_name_here/uploads/users/*/videos",
     "Principal": {
       "AWS": [
         "*"
       ]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Please note that **this policy fragment addresses the *bucket***, where **yours only addresses the *objects* therein** and **both fragments are required** - as mentioned above, this subtle difference is explained in my answer to [Problems specifying a single bucket in a simple AWS user policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089457).

Comment: I am trying to access the video through a web player called JwPlayer. In the same video directories (where the video file resides), there are thumbnails. Even these thumbnails can't be accessed. For the thumbs, I was using the `<img>` element

Comment: PS. I changed my action to `"*"`. See my edit above. Still the same problem. Having `"Action"` `"*"` should give way for the `ListBucket` action as well no?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini: Changing the action to `*` does include `ListBucket` _for the resource at hand_ indeed, **however**, your policy fragment addresses the objects _inside_ the bucket, and `ListBucket` is required for the bucket itself, as explained in more detail in [my other linked answer to a related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9089457) - I've updated my answer to stress that inline here now as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Steffen Opel answer.

Below is what **worked** for me.

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Shahrukh this helped.

Comment: I am glad :) to hear

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Cloudfront default root object to index.html worked for me.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/581268/amazon-cloudfront-with-s3-access-denied

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).